# Error page for MySQL errors

Tags: php, mysql, html

I was wondering if there is any possible way to make MySQL errors cleaner. It's not a very big issue, but if they do happen I'd like them to be nice and neat.

I did read one tutorial, which sadly didn't work, but they did seem to give me hope for a possibility.

I would like my MySQL errors, such as "no connection," to show a error page like a 404 error page.

Anyone know? working tutorials?

Here is the tutorial I read: http://www.jooria.com/Making-Error-Page-When-The-Mysql-Offline-a66.html

Comment: Is this for use in a production environment or just development?

Comment: I think better way to handle them is simply using exceptions.

Comment: Can you explain `which sadly didn't work`? What exactly didn't work about it?  What did you try?

Comment: A custom exception handler is the way to go if you want to be in control of most of the errors, imho.

Answer (score 3):

Add **@** to hide output:

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "*****";
    $dbpwd = "*****";
    $db = "*****";

    $connect = @mysql_pconnect( $host, $dbuser, $dbpwd );
    if( !$connect ) {
        header( 'Location: /custom-404-page.php' ); die;
    } else {
        $select = @mysql_select_db($db);
    }
?>
```

Something like this should work.

```
$result = @mysql_query ($query, $connection );
if ( mysql_error( $connection ) != "" ) {
    header( 'Location: /custom-404-page.php' ); die;
}
```

Or, if you have already headers set, replace `header( 'Location: /custom-404-page.php' );` with:

```
echo '<script>window.location.href="custom-404-page.php";</script>';
```

!Caution: Placing an @ in front of a function call suppresses all error messages. Use it carefully; you can think all is working, when it actually isn't!

Comment: You'll need to do more than `echo '404'` to show an error page...  You need to include a custom page *and* stop page processing with `die` or `exit`.

Comment: Of course, the `echo '404';` was just an example, do after that whatever you want. Put an error message output, redirect to a different page, create your custom 404 page ... etc.

Comment: Okay here is what I've got so far,`<?
$host = "localhost";
$dbuser = "*****";
$dbpwd = "*****";
$db = "*****";
$connect = mysql_pconnect($host, $dbuser, $dbpwd);
if(!$connect)
echo("this is the error");
else
$select = mysql_select_db($db);
?>`

Comment: I'm not sure how I would include it. I swapped echo with, `include ("noconnection.html");` but didn't work.

Comment: Edited the answer with your connection script.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like:

```
$connect = mysql_pconnect($host, $dbuser, $dbpwd);
if(!$connect) {
header('Location: /noconnection.html');
exit();
}
```

If you wanted to do exceptions simply

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($address,$username,$password,$database);
if ($mysqli AND $mysqli->connect_error)
throw new Exception("DB Error ($mysqli->connect_errno): $mysqli->connect_error);
```

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.3+, consider using the [MySQLi version of persistent connection](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php) instead of the deprecated `mysql_pconnect()`

Comment: This example is given based on questioners code. I am sure he will appreciate that input.